# PYTHON - RPA - Aguardar janela PROCESSAMENTO para continuar processo de automação

Tags: python

Estou automatizando a geração de relatórios em um sistema web, SAP. Nesse processo utilizo python, com as bibliotecas: selenium e rpa.

Eu consegui encontrar os campos para inserir as informações, no entanto, após clicar em "Executar", aparece uma pequena janela no centro da tela, escrito "Processando". Enquanto esta janela estiver aberta é sinal que não finalizou a geração do relatório.

Eu gostaria de colocar em meu código algo como "while ('processando'): pause..."

E após esta janela fechar, continuar o processso.

Abaixo tem uma parte do meu código, na qual alguns elementos da página web achei com a selenium, outros com rpa...

```
from selenium import webdriver
import rpa as r
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# 1 - abrindo o navegador
navegador  = webdriver.Chrome()

# 2 - Navegando até o BO
navegador.get("http://123456/BI")

# 3 -Logando
WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,'servletframe')))
WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'logon:USERNAME'))).send_keys('meuusuario')
navegador.find_element_by_id('logon:PASSWORD').send_keys("123")
WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'logon:logonButton'))).click()

#usando rpa para inserir os dados para executar o relatório...

r.init(visual_automation = True,chrome_browser = False)

r.type('assets/CodigoEmpresa.png', '123')
r.click('assets/Executar.png')

#aqui entraria a parte que não sei fazer:
#encontrei essa função present, mas não sei se é assim que usa. 
#Não achei um exemplo no github da rpa..
while (present('Processando.png')):
 pause

#continuando código
```

Essa é a janela que abre enquanto o relatório é gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E abaixo é uma parte do código que encontrei com F12 no navegador:

```
<table role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ariaLabelledBy_waitDlg" oncontextmenu="_CW.eventCancelBubble(event);return false" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="waitDlg" style="display: block; padding: 0px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 179px; left: 558px; width: 250px; height: 150px; z-index: 1005;"><tbody><tr><td style="width:250px;height:150px;" class="dialogbox" id="td_dialog_waitDlg" onresize="_CW.DialogBoxWidget_resizeIframeCB('waitDlg',this)" valign="top"><table class="dlgBox2" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td height="0" valign="top"><table style="height:26" class="dlgTitle" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr valign="top" style="height:26px"><td onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" onmousedown="_CW.DialogBoxWidget_down(event,'waitDlg',this,false);return false;" style="cursor:move;padding-left:10px;" width="100%" valign="middle" align="left"><nobr><span id="ariaLabelledBy_waitDlg" class="titlezone">Executando consulta</span></nobr></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

O XPATH que seria uma opção: //*[@id="waitDlg"], também não localiza.

Eu gostaria de verificar com rpa a imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enquanto existir, fica parado aguardando, após desaparecer é que finalizou a confecção do relatório.

Comment: Eu queria poder  melhorar esta pergunta!!! não vejo como

Comment: é possivel verificar a existencia dessa janela que indica o processamento atravez do selenium?

Comment: Ela some,  não consigo pressionar F12 e inspecionar o nome do elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de tentar o óbvio e consegui.

Para verificar se o popup ainda esta na tela, inseri o comando:

while(r.present('assets/Executando.png')):
r.wait(5)

Acredito que podera ter soluções melhores! Mas também, servirá para ajudar alguém que precise.

Se caso alguém precisar localizar o id de um elemento utilize um programa:

Accessibility Insights For Windows

Ao clicar em qualquer objeto em sua tela, é exibido o id de automação se tiver, name, class e demais propriedades caso tenha.